# Can't enable GCloud debugger for Java 11 with App Engine standard environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-debugger

We are not able to debug our Appengine Standard Java 11 project using Google cloud debugger

```
The debugger could not find a debug target for the application name (project-test).
```

Taking into consideration that The debugger is enabled by default; no configuration is required in App Engine standard environment, as mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#gae-standard)

So what could be the problem and how can I enable the GCloud debugger?

Comment: As we are experiencing the same issue, I filed a ticket in the Java Cloud Debugger repo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java/issues/18

Answer (score 0):

As per the [App Engine documentation regarding issuing HTTP requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests),  if you use URL Fetch, it will cause requests to cloud client libraries (and that includes the Google Cloud Debugger Client for Java) to fail.

Are you using an `appengine-web.xml` file?

If so, does it include the following?

`<url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>`

If that is the case, could you try it without that line?

Comment: we are using app.yaml, for the 2nd gen runtime (java 11), and we are not using urlfetch, so I guess it is something else in our case.